# I have troubles creating a node

Tags: 8

I seem to be having troubles creating a node through the JSON API. I am able to get nodes just fine and generate an access token via oauth but I am having no luck creating anything.

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

This is the content of the CORS file.

```
cors.config:
    enabled: true
    # Specify allowed headers, like 'x-allowed-header'.
    allowedHeaders: ['*']
    # Specify allowed request methods, specify ['*'] to allow all possible ones.
    allowedMethods: ['*']
    # Configure requests allowed from specific origins.
    allowedOrigins: ['*']
    # Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.
    exposedHeaders: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age header.
    maxAge: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
    supportsCredentials: true
```

I also have have the permissions turned on for creating a node for my content type under the consumer. Any suggestions on what I can try next?

These are the permissions for the consumer role.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you turn on the CRUD permissions here `/admin/config/services/jsonapi`?

Comment: The role you assign as scope for your consumer has the permission to create node article?

Comment: @cchen yes it is turned on.

Comment: @Claire D. Yes, that was the first thing I checked. I even turned on create node for anonymous and it didnt work.

Comment: I've added in my cors file. I dont think there is anything wrong with it since I am able to post to oauth to retrieve a token but i thought i would post it anyway.

Comment: You can test with a protected get request, like image style /jsonapi/image_style/image_style (your role should have the permission to manage image style to have access to this) to verify if the generation of your token is correct

Comment: Just tried what you suggested and I get a 200 response using Bearer and my access token. So it must be something else.